# Backbone: Bind won't bind

Tags: javascript, data-binding, backbone.js, coffeescript

Just getting started with backbone, and I *thought* I was familiar with all the caveats around data binding. Turns out I'm not. If anyone has any ideas as to why the following collection isn't being bound to the IndexView I'd be very appreciative. (Have tried both manually in the browser and in chrome console...untriggered console.log call confirms that render() is not being triggered)

From console, attempted call is:

```
window.router.project_view.options.projects.create({name: 'TestProject'})
```

The project is successfully created, but no call to render()

### Router:

```
class Backbonescaffolddemo.Routers.CalendarsRouter extends Backbone.Router

  routes:
    ""           : "index"


  index: () ->

    @projects = new Backbonescaffolddemo.Collections.ProjectsCollection()
    ...
    @project_view = new Backbonescaffolddemo.Views.Projects.IndexView(projects: @projects)
    @task_view = new Backbonescaffolddemo.Views.Tasks.IndexView(tasks: @tasks)
    ...
    $('#projects').html(@project_view.render().el)
```

### Collection/Model:

```
class Backbonescaffolddemo.Models.Project extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  paramRoot: 'project'

class Backbonescaffolddemo.Collections.ProjectsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Backbonescaffolddemo.Models.Project
  url: '/projects'
```

### View:

```
Backbonescaffolddemo.Views.Projects ||= {}

class Backbonescaffolddemo.Views.Projects.IndexView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/projects/index"]

  id: "projects"

  initialize: () ->
    @options.projects.fetch()
    _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll', 'render')
    @options.projects.bind('reset', @addAll)
    @options.projects.bind('save', @addAll)
    @options.projects.bind('change', @addAll)
    @options.projects.bind('change', @render)
    @options.projects.bind('create', @render)

  addAll: () ->
    @options.projects.each(@addOne)

  addOne: (project) ->
    view = new Backbonescaffolddemo.Views.Projects.ProjectView({model: project})
    $(@el).append(view.render().el)

  render: ->
    console.log 'render called'
    $(@el).html(@template(projects: @options.projects.toJSON()))
    return this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a model to a collection, via `create` or by any other means, triggers an `add` event on that collection, not a `create` event. Change

```
@options.projects.bind('create', @render)
```

to

```
@options.projects.bind('add', @render)
```

Comment: Clear, concise, and most importantly - correct. Many thanks. :-)